# How to multiply every other element of an array?

Tags: ruby

Let's say that I have an array like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

how can I multiply every other number of this array except the first by 2
so my new array looks like this

```
[1,4,3,8,5,12,7]
```

Comment: Do you want to multiply every odd indexed value in the array or every even number in the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` and `with_index`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map.with_index{|v,i| i % 2 == 0 ? v : v * 2 } 
# => [1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7]
```

Comment: `i % 2 == 0` can be replaced by [`i.even?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F).

Answer (score 1):

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].each_slice(2).flat_map{|k, l| [k, *(l * 2 if l)]}
# => [1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 12, 7]
```